# Can Tensorflow Custom activation Layer automatic differentiation and don't need to specify the gradient or weight?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My tensorflow is 2.4.0 , but i am using the code in tensorflow 1 base(sess.run), and I want to change my network activation function to my custom type below , which define in the same class

```py
 def new_relu10000(self, x, k=1):
    part_1 = tf.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.less_equal(0.0, x), tf.math.less(x, 10000.0)), dtype=tf.float32)
    part_3 = tf.cast(tf.math.less_equal(10000.0, x), dtype=tf.float32)
    return part_1*x*k + part_3*10000.0
```

and my network is define as

```py
 def _build_a(self, s, scope, trainable):
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(scope):
            net = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(s, 400, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l1', trainable=trainable)
            net2 = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(net,300, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='l2', trainable=trainable)
            a = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(net2, self.a_dim, activation=self.new_relu10000, name='a', trainable=trainable)
            return  a
```

And this code can compile and run successfully(the output of a will never bigger than 10000) , however, I was concerning because I see there are some issue ask by other says that we need to define a gradient of custom activation function , such as
[How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow).
But I also see the answer in here [Tensorflow custom activation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923958/tensorflow-custom-activation-function) says that it will automatic differentiation when using tensor type, but the answer in the same question below says that need to define the weight of custom activation function

So I want to ask is my activation function above is define well and can just use it directly? Or I need to define the gradient part like this question answer [How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow) ?  Or I need to create weights for the activation function Just like the solution here? [Tensorflow custom activation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923958/tensorflow-custom-activation-function)